# "Засыпание" программы на некоторое время

Tags: c#

Нужно приостанавливать программу на некоторое время в некотором месте. Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы между текстом пользователя и выводом ответа проходило некоторое время(вопрос-время-ответ), но при использовании Thread.Sleep() программа засыпает до вывода *вопрос-ответ*(время-вопрос-ответ). Подскажите, как сделать

```
 static void sre_speech(object sender,SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        string answer="Извини, не поняла";
        if (e.Result.Confidence > 0.82)
            {t.Text += "Ivan:>"+e.Result.Text+Environment.NewLine;

            switch (e.Result.Text)
            {
            case "Привет":
                answer = "Привет, Иван";
                break;
            case "Как дела":
                answer = "У меня неплохо :)";
                break;
            case "Сколько времени":
                answer = dt.Hour+":"+dt.Minute+":"+dt.Second;
                break;                
           } 
        }
        Thread.Sleep(1500);

        t.Text += "Caroline:>" + answer + Environment.NewLine;

    }`
  private void form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t = chat;

        CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("ru-ru");
        SpeechRecognitionEngine sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(ci);
        sre.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

        sre.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(sre_speech);

        Choices words = new Choices();
        words.Add(new string[] {"Привет","Как дела","Сколько времени" });

        GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
        gb.Append(words);

        Grammar g = new Grammar(gb);
        sre.LoadGrammar(g);

        sre.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

    }`
```

[image]

Вот вводится пользователем фраза(например, спрашивается , сколько времени) , а ответ должен выводится не сразу, через некоторое время (как некая симуляция обдумывания)

Comment: Не очень понятно, что вы хотите получить и в чём проблема ([минимальный пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) был бы очень кстати), но по формату вопроса могу предположить, что вы пишете приложение с графическим интерфейсом, `sre_speech` - это некий обработчик события приложения, а `t` - это текстовое поле, и оно не обновляется, пока обработчик не завершился. Угадал?

Comment: @yeputons да, программа с распознаванием речи

Comment: @yeputons вот некий пример, возможно, будет понятнее

Comment: Wpf или Windows Forms? И что за переменная 't'?

Comment: Не хватает кода, который вызывает событие. Покажите код вызова обработчика. Опять же,  раз посетили вопрос тегом "многопоточность",  поясните,  в чем она у Вас заключается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почему бы не сделать ваш `sre_speech` асинхронным? (кстати, вы уверены, что обработчик должен быть `static`? Тогда что такое `t` и как оно объявлено?)

```
private async void sre_speech(object sender,SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    await Task.Delay(1500); // вместо Thread.Sleep(1500);
    ...
}
```

**Update:**

Как верно заметил @klutch1991, если все-таки `t` - ссылка на UI контрол, то в итоге это будет выглядеть так:

```
private async void sre_speech(object sender,SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
    string answer="Извини, не поняла";
    if (e.Result.Confidence > 0.82)
    {
        AppendTextToChat("Ivan", e.Result.Text);
        switch (e.Result.Text)
        {
            ... 
        } 
    }
    await Task.Delay(1500);
    AppendTextToChat("Caroline", answer);
}`

private void AppendTextToChat(string name, string text)
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
        () => t.Text += $"{name}:>{text}{Environment.NewLine}");
}
```

Comment: Мне кажется, для этой цели лучше использовать "оконный таймер". Delay будет подвешивать всё приложение.

Comment: почему дилей будет подвешивать все приложение, если єто другой поток, а не основной?

Comment: @nick_n_a где вы это прочли?

Comment: Использование таймера для одной задержки нецелесообразно и нарушает читаемость кода

Comment: Судя по всему `t` - ссылка на контрол с текстом, его значение следует обновлять в UI-потоке. А задержку создавать во вторичном потоке.

Comment: @klutch1991 спасибо, обновил.

Comment: @AGS17 t это textbox, куда выводятся ответы